# Creating sitemap in shareopoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

How to create sitemap in sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2010, there's a webpart called "Table of Contents". It's essentially a site map generator. Might be worth looking at that before writing custom code.